# How does C++ associative containers iterator increment work?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set, associative

For such C++ STLs associative containers like `std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::map` or `std::multimap` iterators.

How `iteratorName++`/`iteratorName--` works?

Does each element have 2 pointers for the very less/more than itself? If so, how does it keep such information?

Does it take O(1), amortized or logarithmic time?

And aside question, how `begin()` method works? Is it considered with each insertion/removal?

Comment: _Exactly_ how it works is up to the implementation. You can look at Open Source implementations like `libstdc++` to see one possible implementation. IIRC, that uses a [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red–black_tree)

Answer (score 0):

> How does C++ associative containers iterator increment work?

The C++ language doesn't specify how the containers are implemented.

In practice, the sorted associative containers are implemented as red-black trees. I'll show one implementation as an example. Libstdc++ map iterator contains a pointer to a tree node. Here is how increment is implemented (modified by me for readability):

```
// modified from libstdc++
// license: lgpl
rb_tree_increment(rb_tree_node_base* x)
{
    if (x->right != 0) 
    {
        x = x->right;
        while (x->left != 0)
            x = x->left;
    }
    else 
    {
        rb_tree_node_base* y = x->parent;
        while (x == y->right) 
        {
            x = y;
            y = y->parent;
        }
        if (x->right != y)
            x = y;
    }
    return x;
}
```

---

> Does it take O(1), amortized or logarithmic time?

All iterator operations are required to be amortized O(1). The worst case non-amortized complexity of the shown implementation is logarithmic.

> how begin() method works?

As you've now learned that you can just read the implementation, I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader to find out.